# How to do a Print Preview in C# crystal reports visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, printing, crystal-reports-2010

I have an application which has two options, to print the report, or to preview the report. I have the following code to print the report-

```
FCPMS.Reports.rptPanelStudy crtrptPanelStudy = new FCPMS.Reports.rptPanelStudy();
crtrptPanelStudy.FileName = tReportFileName; -(refers to the file location on the  computer)
crtrptPanelStudy.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["PANELNUM"].Text = "'5'";
foreach (Table tblTable in crtrptPanelStudy.Database.Tables)
{
    tiInfo = tblTable.LogOnInfo;
    tiInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciConnection;
    tblTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(tiInfo);
}

crtrptPanelStudy.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

This works properly and prints the report. But I am having trouble finding similar code to simply get the printer preview to open with this report. Does anyone know how I could do this? All I need is the printer preview to pop up without the report actually printing. Any help would be appreciated.

I also tried to use Print Dialog -

```
PrintPreviewDialog printpreview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
printpreview.Document = crtrptFlowRangeSummary;
printpreview.ShowDialog();
```

But got this error on the second line

> Error 35 Cannot implicitly convert type `FCPMS.Reports.rptFlowRangeSummary` to `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument`

Comment: have you looked at PrintPreviewDialog ? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog.aspx

Comment: Yes but it did not work. See my edited question for details.

Comment: you need the CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm

Comment: I will post an example let me know if it works for you.

Comment: would need to see how you are actually creating the instance of the Report in case others want to chime in and offer some suggestions

Comment: I added in the rest of the code at the top of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are implementing or declaring crtrptFlowRangeSummary but you can try this code below.

this is also assuming you have the event declared like this

```
private void CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(crtrptFlowRangeSummary !=null)
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crtrptFlowRangeSummary;
}


CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm crystalReportPrintPreview = 
       new CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm(crtrptFlowRangeSummary);
crystalReportPrintPreview.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I do not have that event. It is declared up top (see edited question code) and then the code is in a PrintReport function.

Comment: Take a look at this article it should provide some additional help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633062/solve-nullreference-exception

Comment: What reference must be added for this class 'CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm'